# What direction should the graph be?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

> Graph the function $f(x) = \dfrac{x^2+2x}{x^2-4x+3}$, labelling all intercepts and asymptotes.

I found the vertical and horizonal assymptotes myself.I plugged the problem into an online graph calculator to see how it would look. Why in the top two quartiles and not the bottom two and in between the vertical asymptotes going up but not down?

**My work:**

Vertical Asymptotes:  The process here is

1. Factor
2. Cancel
3. Set denominator $= 0$

$$\frac{x(x+2)}{(x-1)(x-3)}=0 \\ \implies \text{VA's:}\quad x= 1,\quad x=3$$

Horizontal Asymptotes:

$$\frac{x^2}{x^2}=1 \\ \implies \text{HA:}\quad y=1$$

**Here's the graph:**

[image]

Comment: Have you covered limits yet?

Comment: Start with a simpler example: do you understand why the graph of ${1\over x}$ goes to $+\infty$ from the right of the asymptote ($x=0$), but to $-\infty$ from the left?

Comment: No I haven't. Ive been teaching myself  precalc over the summer. For this problem I found a video on finding vertical and horizontal assymptotes

Comment: Well the basic idea is that at a vertical asymptote the function will approach $\infty$ or $-\infty$ from the left and from the right (and as in this example, it might be different directions for each side of the asymptote). The way to figure out which it is is to plug in a number very very close to the asymptote and see if it's very big and positive or very big and negative. For instance, to check the behavior of the function approaching $x=1$ *from the left*, you could plug in $0.99$ and then you'd get about $147$ and can thus be reasonably certain that the graph approaches $+\infty$ there.

Answer (score 1):

If the formula for a function can be expressed as a ratio of two polynomials, then the function can change from being positive to negative or vice versa only at a vertical asymptote or at a place where it crosses the $x$-axis.

In your example, the asymptotes occur at $x = 1$ and $x = 3$.  The zeros occur at $x = 0$ and $x = -2$ (look at the numerator).  So on each of these intervals, the graph of your function must lie above the $x$-axis for the whole interval, or below the axis for the whole interval: $(−∞, -2)$, $(-2,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1, 3)$,  and $(3, +∞).$  We can pick any convenient value in each interval to see where it lies.  This allows us to sketch in some more detail.

In addition, we need to look at the limits at infinity as indicated in the comments to see whether the graph approaches the horizontal asymptote from above or from below.

We can also set the expression equal to 1 and solve for x to find out where the graph crosses the horizontal asymptote.